# Sorting column of action links on grid, error "At least one object must implement IComparable"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, grid

I am building a grid off of a viewmodel with one column being populated with action links. I'm passing in arguments to the action link from an object that's nested within the viewmodel because not all action links will be the same. However, when I go to sort the column consisting of action links, I get an "At least one object must implement IComparable" error. I've tried implementing the IComparable interface in the viewmodel, but I still get the same error. What am I missing?

Here's the view model

```
namespace ViewModels.AlertedUser
{
    public class UserSubmission : IComparable
    {
        public Submission Submission{ get; set; }

        public Link Link{ get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the link class

```
namespace ViewModels.AlertedUser
{
    public class Link
    {
        public string LinkText { get; set; }
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public long Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's the specific grid column

```
<div class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        @(Html
            .Grid(Model.UserSubmission)
            .Build(columns =>
            {
                columns.Add(model => Html.ActionLink(model.Submission.Practice.ID, "Details", "Id", new { model.Submission.Practice.ID }, new { @title = "View ID" })).Titled("ID");                    
                columns.Add(model => model.Submission.Terminal).Titled("Terminal");
                columns.Add(model => model.Submission.Location).Titled("Location");
                columns.Add(model => Html.ActionLink(model.Link.LinkText, model.Link.ActionName, new { id = model.Link.Id})).Titled("Action").Sortable(true);
            })
            .Css("table table-striped table-hover")
            .Empty("No Alerted")
            .Pageable())

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What grid do you use? Is it kendo?

Comment: @Alexander forgot to mention, but I'm using this one: http://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: This code works fine for me, no exception. Could you please post full `@(Html
    .Grid(Model)
    .Build(columns => ...` sample?

Comment: And please specify what version of nuget package do you work with. I'm using `6.1.0`.

Comment: @Alexander Just updated the code block. I'm using version 4.6.0

Comment: Still works fine for me. Do you have `OrderBy` in your controller?